# Eric Hynd's multiselect - databind for optgroup

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, multi-select

I'm using this cool [multiselect component](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) by Eric Hynds.

I have this control databound using knockout in my page. Now I want to allow grouping with my data inside the control. I think I can use the optgroup option as follows:

```
        <select name="example3" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <optgroup label="Group One">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group Two">
        <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="option6">Option 6</option>
        <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>
```

The problem is, in my data the optgroup itself should be some data item. Because I want to show parent-child relationship within this.

Any idea how to do that through databinding?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this view :

```
<select class="fieldValue" data-bind="foreach: availables, value: selectedItem">
    <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: groupName},  foreach: fields">
        <option data-bind="text: headerText, attr:{value: fieldId}"></option>
    </optgroup>
 </select>
```

With this sort of view model :

```
var  vm  ={
    selectedItem:  ko.observable()
    availables :[
        {
            groupName : 'group1'
            fields :[
                fieldId: 0,
                headerText : 'option1',
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi,thanks I'll test this. Any idea how to make optgroup itself is a checkbox?

Comment: You can do it by applying style to the option elements. This post shows you how : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502905/html-checkboxes-in-select-list